# Media de negativos y positivos de una matriz

Tags: python

Podrian por favor colaborarme a orgaanizar este algoritmo, necesito hallar la media de negativos y positivos y asi mismo la cantidad de negativos y positivos.Agradezco su colaboracion.

```
vect = [[float() for i in range(50)] for j in range(50)]
    print ("ingrese el numero de filas y columnas sucesivamente: ")
    n = float(input())
    m = float(input())
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print ("numero de fila ",i)
        for j in range(1,m+1):
            vect[i-1][j-1] = float(raw_input())

        positivos = 0
        negativos = 0
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            for j in range(1,m+1):
                if vect[i-1][j-1]>0:
                    pos = pos+vect[i-1][j-1]
                else:
                    neg = neg+vect[i-1][j-1]
        print ("la sumatoria de los positivos es ",positivos)
        print ("la sumatoria de los negativos es ",negativos)


        for i in range(len(vector)):
            numero = input()
            if numero>0:
                positivos = positivos+1
            else:
                if numero<0:
                    negativos = negativos+1
        print (" cantidad de positivos: ",positivos)
        print (" cantidad de negativos: ",negativos)
```

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que ya tienes cargada la matriz en memoria, con tu procedimiento  `float(raw_input())` si estás usando **Python 2.7** o `float(input())` si estás usando **Python 3.x**, entonces puedes calcular la cantidad y suma rápidamente recorriendo cada fila, ir comparando cada valor si es mayor o menor que 0 y luego acumulándolos en 2 listas, una para positivos y otra para negativos. Una vez que tienes las listas, puedes aplicarles operaciones.

```
vect = [[3.6, -1.2, 2.4], [6.0, 8, -5.5], [-1.3, -4.1, 7.4]] # Una matriz de prueba
positivos = []
negativos = []
for row in vect:
    positivos.extend([x for x in row if x >= 0])
    negativos.extend([x for x in row if x < 0])

print("Cantidad de positivos:", len(positivos))
print("Sumatoria de positivos:", sum(positivos))
print()
print("Cantidad de negativos:", len(negativos))
print("Sumatoria de negativos:", sum(negativos))
```

> ```
> Cantidad de positivos: 5
> Sumatoria de positivos: 27.4
>
> Cantidad de negativos: 4
> Sumatoria de negativos: -12.1
> ```